# Сравнение схожести двух масивов

Tags: php, массивы, wordpress

Есть два массива:

```php
$user_role = $user_data->roles;
$post_role = get_field('choose_user_role', $child->ID);
```

такого типа:

```
Array([0] => top_manager [1] => manager)
```

Хочу проверить не содержит ли `$post_role` хотябы одно совпадение с `$user_role`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вам нужна функция [`in_array`](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.in-array.php), которая ищет вхождение элемента в массив.

```
if (in_array($post_role, $user_role)) {
    // если условие выполнилось, то элемент содержится в массиве
}
```

Для проверки наличия элементов, содержащихся в обоих массивах, можно использовать функцию [`array_intersect`](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.array-intersect.php)

```
// в $intersection запишутся элементы, содержащиеся в обоих массивах.
$intersection = array_intersect($post_role, $user_role);
```

Comment: ругается на то что $post_role не массив, хотя при выводе возвращает массив

Comment: Прошу прощения, я думал, что `$post_role` - это массив. Сейчас поправлю.

Comment: array_intersect(): Argument #1 is not an array

Comment: Это значит, что у вас на самом деле не два массива, и `$post_role` является чем-то другим.

Comment: `array (size=3)
  0 => string 'top_manager' (length=11)
  1 => string 'manager' (length=7)
  2 => string '' (length=0)`
and
`array (size=1)
  0 => string 'administrator' (length=13)`

Comment: Боюсь, `array_intersect` просто рапортует о том, что получает. Возможно, переменная изменяется где-то "в пути".